# Calling functions in a LINQ query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

My question is that how to call a function in LINQ query? e.g

```
source.Where(x=> double.Parse(x.Col1)==3)
```

or

```
source.Where(x=> AnyUserFunction(x.Col1)==true)
```

Basically my requirement is to check weather Col1 is a numeric value or not, but I occasionally need to call my User Defined functions as well.

Comment: How do you expect that to work with SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your Linq to Entities provider doesn't know how to translate your custom methods to SQL. The solution proposed by @teovankot is the easy way to solve this problem, but if you want to work with [Linq to Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) I suggest you use [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method instead `ToList` because `AsEnumerable` does not execute the query until you consult the data, it preserves [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx), but be careful, try to don't use `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` on the entire `DbSet` because you'd retrieve all rows of that table affecting your application's performance.

Now if you only want to check weather `Col1` is a numeric value or not,  another solution could be using [SqlFunctions.IsNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric(v=vs.110).aspx) method which is translated into native SQL:

```
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
//...

source.Where(x=> SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(x.Col1)==1);
```

You can find another set of functions you can also call in the [`DbFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) static class.`SqlFunctions` are SQL Server specific, whereas `DbFunctions` aren't.

Comment: I am not in a state to test the answer but it sould work as already used SqlFunctions successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call user defined functions easy in linq to sql.

But you can do it after you get all your data from DB to your server. Like this:

```
 source.ToList().Where(x=> AnyUserFunction(x.Col1)==true)
```

Note `ToList()` call. this will get all your data from DB so you basically working with linq to objects where you can easy use your user defined fucntions.

Comment: I cant afford to fetch all the data from db

Comment: I understand you, then @octavioccl answer definatly helps you